# Is there a Budgie theme configuration GUI or tweak tool?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.3, then I wanted to install Budgie desktop environment. However, I could not find any theme changing GUI or tweak tool? Is there one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change themes on Budgie you can use the desktop settings panel `Raven`, just click the power button

[image]

You can change most desktop related settings here.

If you want a more robust tweak tool application, you can use `gnome-tweak-tool`

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Budgie is based on Gnome and this will work fine.